# is there a way to get values of a map of pair and value by the key pair only?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this map `static Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> wordTopic = new HashMap<>();`

Basically it's a matrix , and i want all the values of specific string(the key of the pair)..AKA all the values of one row..

This will get the sum of one row ,but i have no idea how to get the row itself,each value all in an array or something.

```
   wordTopic.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .sum();
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: You may want a `Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>` - that way your data is correctly indexed. Also, consider using a Guava [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

Comment: this will change all my project structure lol @BoristheSpider

Comment: expected result is an array of the values that has that  "string" in the pair regardless the int in the pair @YCF_L

Comment: The point of a `Map` is to provide lookup by index - given you are looping over the `Map` searching in linear time; your structure is likely wrong...

Comment: i know it is wrong , but i have just noticed this bug late..but i need a temporarly solution now then i will change the structure later @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a method as such:

```
int[] getValuesByKey(Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> map, String key) {
      return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .toArray();
}
```

which given a map and a key will yield all the values where the entry key is equal to the provided key.

or if you want an `Integer` array then you can do:

```
Integer[] getValuesByKey(Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> map, String key) {
      return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

or if you want to retrieve a list.

```
List<Integer> getValuesByKey(Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> map, String key) {
      return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Comment: Why `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` rather than `toList`? Seems unneccessarily verbose.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it’s only unnecessarily verbose if you’re not concerned about the mutability of the list returned. Most people are used to creating an ArrayList which is mutable in order to accumulate the elements. However, if the OP doesn’t care whether the list is mutable or not then I’d leave that as a exercise for them to have a look at the Collectors API.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a collector at the end of the stream like that :

```
wordTopic.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
            .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and here you go

Comment: Please change last line to `.collect(...)`

Comment: Why `mapToInt` and then `collect`? That just unboxes and then boxes again - rather a waste of CPU cycles. Use `toArray` if you want to create a primitive collection.